# How to use ImageMagick with Alfresco?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, compression, alfresco

I know Alfresco uses imagemagick for preview of images however I want to use imagemagick when uploading images to ALfresco. So that only compressed images are stored in repository.

Any idea how can I achieve this either my manipulating configurations of Alfresco or I need to do it with some programming?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options. First, you could write a rule which would be triggered when objects of a certain mimetype are added to a folder. Your custom rule code could then invoke a transformation to compress the image and then delete the source file. One drawback to this approach is that the original file does exist in the repo for a time. The second drawback is that you'd have to configure it on every folder. [This tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html) explains how to write a custom rule action.

The second option would be to implement a behavior. Your custom behavior code can look for a node creation event and take action when it sees one happen. When it sees an image it could then invoke a transformation and replace the original. [This tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/behaviors/tutorial/tutorial.html) explains how to write custom behaviors.

The third option would be to do a much lower level extension of the node service, so that the original object never actually gets created but is first compressed. That would be much more involved than either of the options above.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have a JavaScript based Webscript which opt my client to upload files. I will incorporate Option 2 in my existing Webscript, I need to run a command of ImageMagick on beforeCreateNode behavior.

Comment: I tried to run commands related to imagemagick on my existing webscript but none is working.... I am using JS based webscript. Any idea how can I run commands in ALfresco?